# Java overriding methods

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a little confusion in Java overriding. Suppose we have the following inheritance:

```
class A{
    public A(){    
    }

    void show(){
        System.out.println("SuperClass");
    }
}

class B extends A{

    @Override
    void show(){
        System.out.println("SubClass");
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      B b = new B();
      b.show();
    }  
}
```

Clearly, `class B` overrides the method `show()` that is inherited by the `class A`. Why is not `b.show();` printing the message `System.out.println("SuperClass");` as well since `class B` has now the method `show()` from `class A`?

Thank you.

Comment: What would be the point of overriding methods if it did ?

Comment: @sp00m kind of. The method is still there though since you can access it with `super`.

Comment: hello Mike with relation to the inheritance , its the matter of polymorphism which acts , i.e., method call to method body happens at run time i.e when jvm invoke B b=new B(); so the B object is of type class B so the method it displays B's method which is overridden one, if you put super() you can get parents one.

Answer (score 14):

The `show` method of class B overrides the show method of class A and doesn't call it, so there's no reason for `System.out.println("SuperClass");` to be executed when you call `show` on an instance of B.

If you change class B to :

```
class B extends A 
{
    @Override
    void show(){
        super.show ();
        System.out.println("SubClass");
    }
}
```

calling `show` on an instance of B will also execute the logic of `A`'s show method.

Comment: @benzonico My mistake. It should be `super.show()`. `super()` is for calling a super class's constructor. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: `super()` cannot be used in methods unless constructors.

Answer (score 3):

In class `B` you are overriding, in other words **replacing** the original implementation of the `show()` method. Every time you invoke `show()` on an object that is `instanceof B` that version of the method will be called.

The only way to refer to the original `show()` method is to refer to it using the `super.show()` syntax inside `B` or any other class that extends `A`.

And as an additional note, that `@Override` annotation is just to add additional compiler checks but it's not required to actually override a method, you just need to re-implement it as you have done in `B`.

Answer (score 3):

its the matter of polymorphism which acts , i.e., method call to method body happens at run time i.e when JVM invokes B b=new B(); so B object is of type class B ,so the method it displays B's method which is overridden one, if you put super() in B()'s constructor you can get parents one.

Answer (score 2):

This is the effect of overriding in inheritance. You just replace the method from the superclass (but you can still reach the old one!) Here I also added a little bit with polymorphism too. Hope that this will help you.

```
class A{
    public A(){    
    }

    void show(){
        System.out.println("SuperClass");
    }
}

class B extends A{

    void superclass() {
        super.show();
    }

    @Override
    void show(){
        System.out.println("SubClass");
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      B b = new B();
      b.show(); //SubClass
      b.superclass(); //SuperClass

      A a = new A();
      a.show(); //SuperClass

      A c = new B();
      c.show(); //SubClass
      //c.superclass(); //error! the program won't compile
    }  
}
```

Comment: Make it //c.superclass(); error! the program won't compile